# Wiring help with ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling-fan, fans

Massive struggle with wiring, just purchased ceiling fan and don't understand the two yellow wires and 3 red wires. Any recommendations?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ibZN.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Voting to close. Questions remain unanswered and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what devices were powered by the black / yellow / red wires.  Providing more information will make it easier for others to help you.  It would also be helpful to know if you are working in a 120V environment (USA) or 240V environment.

I would attempt to identify the [hot and neutral wires](https://www.dummies.com/programming/electronics/components/alternating-current-in-electronics-hot-neutral-and-ground-wires/) with a volt meter.  This is the minimum.  If you do not have experience working with volt meters, I suggest that you find someone that does to help and provide safety guidance.

It would not surprise me if the red and black potential difference was 120V (assuming you are in the USA).  `Drawing a diagram is helpful to understanding the wiring system.`

Comment: Hi Gator, the yellow wires are powering the smoke detector which is attached to the light.

Comment: Can you measure the potential difference between  wire pairs  and post the measurements?

Comment: @PájaPája how is a smoke detector attached to a light? never seen or heard of that before

Comment: @Alex I've seen detectors on lighting circuits before so that when the internal battery fails, the occupant must replace the battery. Else they will have no lighting.

Comment: @ChristopherTaylor thought he meant physically attached, although now that I re-read it I get the gist better.